# Jquery sticky nav add background-color when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I just installed jquery sticky nav to my website, it works great, when I do have to scroll down, I want my nav to stay at the top, but add a background color, is this possible?

```
#navigation {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
z-index: 10000000;
}

<div id="navigation-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 172px;">
<div id="navigation">
</div>
</div>

$("#navigation").sticky({topSpacing:0});
```

I tried adding a background-color to the class is-sticky:

```
.is-sticky {
        background-color: #000;
}
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Do you have a link to a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `.is-sticky` class even being applied to the navigation on scroll? Because your code would work if it was. Or within the jQuery you could just chain a CSS change:

```
$("#navigation").sticky({topSpacing:0}).css({'background':'#000'});
```